# Number value in textbox to add commas

Tags: c#, string, numbers, format

I have tried adding a button to add commas inside as shown below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    Number.Text = "";
    string s = string.Format("{0:n0}",1234567890);
    Number.Text += "value : 1234567890";
    Number.Text += "<br />Thousands Separator: " + s;

    Number.Text += "<br/><br />another solution";
    int value = 1234567890;
    string formatedstring = value .ToString("#,##0");
    Number.Text += "<br />result: " + formatedstring;
}
```

However, I want this to change as soon as I type it in, similar to an update function in Unity. Adding a button function is very unethical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an event for text changed in the textbox. Then add the following code:

```
 void numberTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string value = numberTextBox.Text.Replace(",", "");
      ulong ul;
      if (ulong.TryParse(value, out ul))
      {
        numberTextBox.TextChanged -= numberTextBox_TextChanged;
        numberTextBox.Text = string.Format("{0:#,#}", ul);
        numberTextBox.SelectionStart = numberTextBox.Text.Length;
        numberTextBox.TextChanged += numberTextBox_TextChanged;
      }
    }
```